# python regex include exceptions in the regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for expressions as Vc Am in texts and for that I have

```
rex = r"(\(?)(?<!([A-Za-z0-9]))[A-Z][a-z](?!([A-Za-z0-9]))(\)?)"
```

explanation:

```
[A-Z][a-z] = Cap followed by lower case letter 
(?<!([A-Za-z0-9])) -> lookbehind not being a letter or number
(?!([A-Za-z0-9]))(\)?) _ Look ahead not being letter or number
# all that optionally wihtin parenthesis

import re
text="this is Vc and not Cr nor Pb"
matches = re.finditer(rex,text)
```

What I want to achieve is exclude a list of terms like Cr or Pb.

How should I include exceptions in the expression?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's shorten your RegEx:

- `(?<!([A-Za-z0-9]))` -> lookbehind not being a letter or number
- `(?!([A-Za-z0-9]))(\)?)` -> look ahead not being letter or number

these are so common there is a RegEx feature for them: Word boundaries `\b`. They have zero width like lookarounds and only match if there is no alphanumeric character.

Your RegEx then becomes `\b[A-Z][a-z]\b`; looking at this RegEx (and your examples), it appears you want to match certain element abbreviations?

Now you can simply use a lookbehind:

[`\b[A-Z][a-z](?<!Cr|Pb)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/3QmDls/1)

to assert that the element is neither Chrome nor Lead.

---

Just for fun:

Alternatively, if you want a less readable (but more portable) RegEx that makes do with fewer advanced RegEx features (not every engine supports lookaround), you can use character sets as per the following observations:

- If the first letter is not a `C` or `P`, the second letter may be any lowercase letter;
- If the first letter is a `C`, the second letter may not be an `r`
- If the first letter is a `P`, the second letter may not be an `b`

Using character sets, this gives us:

- `[ABD-OQ-Z][a-z]`
- `C[a-qs-z]`
- `P[ac-z]`

Operator precedence works as expected here: Concatenation (implicit) has higher precendence than alteration (`|`). This makes the RegEx `[ABD-OQ-Z][a-z]|C[a-qs-z]|P[ac-z]`. Wrapping this in word boundaries using a group gives us [`\b([ABD-OQ-Z][a-z]|C[a-qs-z]|P[ac-z])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sVmVye/2).

Answer (score 2):

You might write the pattern without using the superfluous capture groups, and exclude matching `Cr` or `Pb`:

```
\(?(?<![A-Za-z0-9])(?!Cr\b|Pb\b)[A-Z][a-z](?![A-Za-z0-9])\)?
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QCzFuF/1) for the matches.

---

If you are not interested in matching the parenthesis, and you also do not want to allow an underscore along with the letters or numbers, you can use a word boundary instead:

```
\b(?!Cr\b|Pb\b)[A-Z][a-z]\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `Cr\b|Pb\b` Match either `Cr` or `Pb`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[A-Z][a-z]` Match a single uppercase and single lowercase char
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AK9XFS/1)